# NextJS 9.3 Link not a constructor function for JSX elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

trying to create a Link element with a title and a slug for href.

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import styled from 'styled-components';

type Props = {
  title: string;
  slug: string;
};

const NavElement = ({ title, slug }: Props) => {
  return (
    <Link href={slug}>
      <a>{title}</a>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default NavElement;
```

Dependencies in package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.9.34",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "contentful": "^7.14.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "next": "9.3.5",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.0"
  }
```

Getting this error:

```
JSX element type 'Link' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Type 'Link' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, and 2 more.ts(2605)
JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property.ts(2607)
```

Been through nextjs docs and previous cases where I've done it and for the life of me cannot spot what is wrong. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a return statement if you wrap around braces

Try this ...

```
const NavElement = ({ title, slug }: Props) => (
  <Link href={slug}>
    <a>{title}</a>
  </Link>;
);
```

or this

```
const NavElement = ({ title, slug }: Props): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Link href={slug}>
      <a>{title}</a>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

Comment: Same issue remains. Updated though as a valid observation form code formatting perspective.

Comment: That should most definitely . Tested the same on my next server and works like a charm. Try restarting your server.

Comment: Or try explicitly defining the return type of the function and see if you get the typescript warning. `const NavElement = ({ title, slug }: Props): JSX.Element => {`

Comment: No change. I'm guessing it has somethign to do with the dependencies. Perhaps some kind of conflict..

Comment: Can you provide a link to a repro? Just tried the same code in my Nextjs project. Running `"next": "9.3.2"` though.

Comment: Proprieate repo so no. However, found out that declare module React was included in the projext, which interfered with the Link. Removed that declaration and Link works as intended.